# TreeNode mouse hover tooltip not showing up

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, mousehover

I am trying to show a tooltip when mouse hovers on a treeview node. But the tooltip is not showing up.

This is my code:

```
private void treeView1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.RemoveAll();

    TreeNode selNode = (TreeNode)treeView1.GetNodeAt(Cursor.Position);

    if (selNode != null)
    {
        if (selNode.Tag != null)
        {
            Product selProduct = selNode.Tag as Product;

            if (selProduct != null)
            {
                toolTip1.SetToolTip(treeView1, selProduct.ProductName + "\n" + selProduct.ProductCategory.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I check for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like the problem is in the

```
TreeNode selNode = (TreeNode)treeView1.GetNodeAt(Cursor.Position);
```

line, change it to

```
TreeNode selNode = (TreeNode)treeView1.GetNodeAt(treeView1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
```

and it should work; I would also recomd to look at the following article: [How to add a ToolTip to a TreeNode in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322634) for detalis on how to add tooltips to the treeview

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Tooltips are displayed automatically when you enable them, as explained in the next answer. There's no need to handle the `MouseHover` event.

Answer (score 36):

A much simpler way is to:

1. Set the ToolTipText on the TreeNode when you create it.
2. Set the TreeView control's ShowNodeToolTips property to True.

And you're done.